# How to define a specific row height for Word table row similarly 'Row Height' feature in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

In Excel we have 'Row Height' where we can enter a number to define the heihgt of a row.

I want to do the same in Word but there is no such command when right clicking on the row. And currently we have to do that by hand dragging the row border - though, this can hardly make multiple rows stay the same height.

In Excel

[image]

In Word

[image]

Answer (score 3):

#### Adjusting Table Row Height

> Word allows you to independently adjust the height of every row in a table. For many table uses, you can rely on Word to select an automatic row height. There may be other times when you want to take charge and specify your own row height.
>
> You can do so by following these steps if you are using Word 97 or
>   Word 2000:
>
> - Select the table row whose height you want to specify.
> - Choose the Cell Height and Width option from the Table menu. You will see the Cell Height and Width dialog box. The Row tab should
>     be selected.
> - In the Height of Row box, select the way you want row height to be determined. You can use Auto row height, At Least row height, or
>     Exactly row height.
> - If you selected At Least row height or Exactly row height, specify a measurement in the At dialog box.
> - Click on OK.
>
> In Word 2002 and Word 2003, the steps are slightly different:
>
> - Select the table row whose height you want to specify.
> - Choose Table Properties from the Table menu. Word displays the Table Properties dialog box.
> - On the Row tab, choose the Specify Height check box.
> - Specify a height and how you want that measurement interpreted (At Least or Exactly).
> - Click on OK.

Source [Adjusting Table Row Height](http://word.tips.net/T001667_Adjusting_Table_Row_Height.html)