# Why table row height can't be reduced in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have copied the attached table from a website but I can't figure out why the row height can't be reduced. I even set the cell margin to 0 for both four sides. But still no improvement.

[Sample Word File Here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/j31sjmomedp55axuo8b5z/superuser.docx?dl=0&rlkey=0ldhs3qgdkjwcmcpbcqueb8ey)

Any help will be appreciated showing the cause and solution of this problem.

Thanks

Comment: While links to external resources might be helpful, questions on this site should be self contained. Add all the relevant details of the table directly into the question body including the styles of the table content.

Comment: Related: [Decreasing table row height in Word 2011 (possibly specific issue with end of row formatting)](https://superuser.com/q/1054422/152004), [How to define a specific row height for Word table row similarly 'Row Height' feature in Excel?](https://superuser.com/q/802574/152004)

Answer (score 0):

I've had a look at your file.

It seems your table is corrupted, although I set "Same as the whole table" in "table properties" / "cell" / "options" it doesn't get saved.

I could fix it by converting the table to text ("table tools" / "layout" / "convert to text") then converting it to table ("insert" / "table" / "convert text to table")

Comment: Please download the attached word file from my question. I have tried your solutions before asking the question here in this forum but failed. So, please download the file and try whether the problem is for that issues or not and let me know Thanks

Comment: please see my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's not possible to reduce the height of a row or rows because of the font size set within the rows. Setting the font size to a really low value will often resolve this, even if there is no text in the row or cells affected.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's easier just to recreate the table. You can set the shell up and then copy the contents over. Doing so apparently doesn't bring over the corruption.